How would platypus evolve some sort of digestive acid?
Platypus doesn't have any gastric acid, they've lost them because of their diet of hard shelled prey, say they were seeded into a terraformed world and expand to new niches, how would they "re-evolve* digestive acid so that they can expand to scavenging niche.

Have a close look at how have they lost it perhaps, are the genes still there or just switched off? if they're just switched off then they can be switched back on again the same way an occasional cow can be born with a leg on it's back (a random mutation turns on the 'limb' development for the dorsal fin all mammals had way back when we were fish and a 'fin' develops according to the DNA blueprint the animal has stored & linked where the fin growing instructions used to be and presto! it grows an extra leg flopping around on its back) that's your most likely route if the genes are still there.

"A platypus is a duck designed by a committee" ... fire the committee and what you are left with will be a perfectly passable duck.

Evolving a functioning stomach from scratch is very unlikely for a complex organism. The easiest way is probably that some of their progeny happens to activate some dormient genes, in the same way as sometimes people are born with a tail, and so they have a barely functional stomach.
If that would give them a competitive advantage in their environment, they would have better chances of mating and to carry over the feature to their progenies.
Keep in mind that evolution is not a cooking recipe, where given the initial ingredients and the preparation steps the outcome will always be the same: from the same unicellular being floating in the primordial soup we have seen evolving trees and the elephants feeding on them.

The thing is that platypus lost their genes for stomach acid, so can they re evolve acid for digestion somewhere? Like maybe saliva or other things

Not all platypus have the same pH in their stomachs. If having a lover pH is advantageous, natural selection will favour those platypus with more acidic stomachs and eventually arrive to a result similar to gastric acid. The structures involved in producing that sort of gastric acid may end looking similar to those of other mammals that never lost them, or may end being very different. The panda's thumb is an example of a similar setting, where a lost trait has been evolved in a surprising different way.
However, take in account that gastric acid doesn't exist in isolation but as part of a system. Having gastric acids means also change the stomach wall, change diet, and so. Furthermore, the trait selected by evolution is not having gastric acid but being able to digest some kind of stuff. It's possible that platypus evolve a different way to digest it that don't involve gastric acids, just like both cows and orangutans digest leaves, but only the former have four stomachs to digest them.

platypi don't have a stomach, that why they lost the ability to produce gastric acid

@John is the DNA code for it gone or just bypassed or switched off do you know?

We like orangutans also digest leaves, the reason neither we nor orangutans need four stomachs to do that is because neither of us only eat leaves so the fact that we may only digest them poorly is not a problem for us because we also have fruits and nuts etc, a poor choice of example, a better one would be pandas perhaps? that amply demonstrate the problems with relying exclusively on a food source you're not properly equipped to digest by having to spend practically every waking minute eating.

It's inevitable
Or, at least highly likely that, given the evolutionary pressures, the platypus would re-evolve stomach acid functionally similar to that of most other mammals.
When different organisms independently evolve similar mechanisms for dealing with similar evolutionary pressures its called convergent evolution. It happens a lot.
For example:

All swimming animals are streamlined and have fins or flippers;
Eyes have evolved several times;
Birds and bats separately evolved flight;
the opposable thumbs of primates (including us) are evolutionary different from the opposing thumbs of giant pandas.

So, if there is an evolutionary advantage to a neo-platypus in evolving stomach acid, then all that's needed for that to happen is sufficient time for the right mutation to take place. Once it does, natural selection will ensure it becomes dominant.
But I'm going one step further - its highly likely that this will not only be functionally similar, but it will be chemically identical subject only to variations in concentration (scavengers and carnivores have higher concentrations than herbivores or carnivores feeding on phylogenetically distant prey). That's because the enzymes are already there and that limits the chemical pathways such that the same chemical composition is so likely as to be almost certain.
